# how to test if "\u" is contained in unicode Python strings?

Tags: regex, string

I have a list of unicode strings. I want to test if "\u" is a substring in each string element so as to take action for specific cases, how to achieve this?

I was programming in Python. I have a Japanese to English dict in Python, I plan to replace the Japanese in each string into the corresponding English word.

In the following example, \u819c indeed correspond to one Japanese Character, \u539a correspond to another Japanese Character, they together become a Japanese word. I have a dictionary that map this word to English, now I want to replace 
"\u819c\u539a" by the English word. Because Japanese and English are mixed, what I want to do is to first determine if it is a pure asii string or an unicode string. That is why I am trying to check "\u" in the string

```
[u'\u819c\u539a_act', u'wild\u5e45', u'Hello_world', u'hello']
```

I expect answer to be

```
True, True, False, False
```

Comment: You are asking us to do the impossible :-). Your first string is "u'膜厚_act'" in fact, so there is no way it matches the pattern represented by "\u".

Comment: Well, its my guess. I think OP is asking if a string contains unicode characters?

Comment: Please mention programming environment you'll be using for regex

Comment: That's the confusion. Everything can be expressed as a unicode in Java using the `\u` escape sequence followed by four hex characters. For instance, in Java, the character `'\u0061'` and `'a'` both represent the ASCII character 'a'. If the string is like "\\u0061", should `True` be printed?

Comment: I was programming in Python. I have a Japanese to English dict in Python, I plan to replace the Japanese in each string into the corresponding English word.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is to treat every string as a Unicode string and see if a string contains a character whose Unicode code-point is more than a certain value of your choice. Consider the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] c1 = new char[]{'\'', '\u819c', '\u539a', '\u0061', 'a'};
    String[] strs = new String[]{new String(c1)};
    for (String s : strs) {
       s.codePoints().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Here, I picked certain characters from a string you used. Running this program prints:

```
39
33180
21402
97
97
```

Note that fourth and fifth characters are the same, although one is expressed as a [unicode sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html). Would you consider the character 'a' being expressed as `\u0061` a "Unicode character"? Ideally, you should, because every character has a Unicode code-point. But then again, what you should do depends on your requirements.

The 2nd and the 3rd character are what that you seem to be interested in identifying. And you want to know if a string contains *such* characters (perhaps Chinese characters). If that's what you are looking for, then you should consult the Unicode spec, find out the code-points of characters (or their ranges) that you want to identify and handle the strings containing them the way you need to.

Thus, in the above code if you did something like

```
       s.codePoints().filter(c -> c > 4296).forEach(System.out::println);
```

you could filter out the non-Chinese characters, producing the output:

```
33180
21402
```